# Anchor Links Changes Based on Site/Device Width?

Tags: jquery, html, css

So, on my website, I am using a smoothscroll script and I am using anchor ids to reference the scrolling points on page.

The Anchor Code is Simple, Like This:

```
<a id="about"></a>
```

And it does work when using a regular href, however, I noticed when I was on my phone, that when pressing the anchor links, it would take me to a random point on the div, and not at the anchor's exact location on page. It seems like this changes per device (e.g. some will be above the anchor, some will be below, based on device width)

It's just a basic javascript, is there a way to make the anchor point *absolute?*

Comment: can you share the script/plugin you are using?

Comment: You are asking what's wrong in this anonymous script

Comment: Here: https://www.tinii.biz/hashtag-scroll.js

Comment: try to style your anchor tags with `@media` queries. In that way, every device width will apply diferent style for anchor tags.

Comment: @Aleksandar Yeah, I spent 5 hours trying, I've been having no luck with media queries.